# How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: geolocation, timezone, latitude-longitude

Given the latitude and longitude of a location, how does one know what time zone is in effect in that location?

In most cases, we are looking for an IANA/Olson time zone id, although some services may return just a UTC offset, or some other time zone identifier.  Please read the [timezone tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for details.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is the lack of any UTC timestamp requirement when determining the time zone. For instance, a long/lat in London is not enough to determine weather the time zone is GMT or BST (British Summer Time / daylight savings). So surely to determine the correct time zone you need lat, long and a UTC timestamp.

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall - To determine whether you are in GMT (UTC+0000) or BST (UTC+0100) - yes, you are absolutely correct.  But those are time zone *offsets*, not time zone identifiers.  Both are covered by the same `"Europe/London"` time zone identifier of the IANA time zone database.

Comment: Ah okay, and the daylight savings offset will be added (if required) once rendering a time with a given time zone identifier?

Comment: @Michael - that depends on the specific implementation, but usually, yes.

Comment: It's still may require UTC timestamp. For example Russia change timezones boundarys 4 times for last 6 years.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia

Comment: do you have any info about what @Arnial sad? Use lat and long + UTC timestamp to determine Timezone? Or some place that give historical GeoJsons ??

Comment: @thur - lat+lon are enough to determine *time zone* with one of the options here.  For example, `55.75, 37.62` is enough to get `"Europe/Moscow"`.  You'll need a timestamp and a time zone database to determine the *offset* from UTC for that location at a given time.  For example `Europe/Moscow @ 2016-01-01T00:00:00 => UTC+3` but `Europe/Moscow @ 2014-01-01T00:00:00 => UTC+4`.  See "time zone != offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: @thur - As far as the boundaries themselves go, there are some historical differences from year to year as border disputes start or end.  However, when a shift like the one Arnial described occurs, the tzdb creates a new time zone for the affected region, so all time in that region is accounted for - including historical differences.  We call this a "zone split".  A good Russian example would be `Europe/Astrakhan`, which split away from `Europe/Volgograd` with tzdb 2016b.

Comment: Shouldn't the input be both location and UTC time as time zones may change for the same exact location if the time changes?

Comment: @naaz -no.  Read the comment thread just above.

Comment: See also [SO community wiki for timezone tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @Sero. Yes.  cldr.unicode.org's "metazones.xml" includes historical changes. [Current metazones.xml](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/release-36-1/common/supplemental/metaZones.xml). Specifically, in addition to the current metazone, for each "timezone id" it shows which "metazone" was in effect for each date range. (Somewhere else there must be a spec as to the time offset rules for a metazone. E.g. the "standard" time offset, and the date range per year which offsets by 1 hr for DST.) I ask how to extract some info from this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/264083/70416).

Comment: @Sero - presumably, the various APIs and offline libraries mentioned in the accepted answer make use of similar historical info, as well as daylight savings time rules. (The exact date at which DST starts/ends is specific to the year, as set by the geo-political entity containing the lat/long location.)

Answer (score 622, accepted):

**Time Zone Location Web Services**

- [Google Maps Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)
- [Bing Maps Time Zone API](https://learn.microsoft.com/bingmaps/rest-services/timezone/)
- [Azure Maps Time Zone API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone)
- [GeoNames Time Zone API](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone)
- [TimeZoneDB API](https://timezonedb.com/api)
- [GeoTimeZone.com](https://www.geotimezone.com/)
- [AskGeo](https://askgeo.com/) - commercial (but [arguably more accurate than GeoNames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519523/634824))
- [GeoGarage Time Zone API](https://www.geogarage.com/blog/news-1/post/geogarage-time-zone-api-31) - commercial, focusing on Nautical time zones.

**Raw Time Zone Boundary Data**

- [Timezone Boundary Builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) - builds time zone shapefiles from OpenStreetMaps map data. Includes territorial waters near coastlines.

The following projects have previously been sources of time zone boundary data, but are no longer actively maintained.

- [tz_world](http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/) - the original shapefile data from Eric Muller
- [whereonearth-timezone](https://github.com/straup/whereonearth-timezone) - GeoJSON version with WOEDB data merged in

**Time Zone Geolocation Offline Implementations**

Implementations that use the Timezone Boundary Builder data

- [node-geo-tz](https://github.com/evansiroky/node-geo-tz) - JavaScript library (Node.js only)
- [browser-geo-tz](https://github.com/kevmo314/browser-geo-tz) - JavaScript library
- [timespace](https://github.com/mapbox/timespace) - JavaScript library
- [tz-lookup-oss](https://github.com/darkskyapp/tz-lookup-oss/) - JavaScript library
- [GeoTimeZone](https://github.com/mj1856/GeoTimeZone) - .NET library
- [Geo-Timezone](https://github.com/minube/geo-timezone) - PHP library
- [timezonefinder](https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinder) - Python library
- [ZoneDetect](https://github.com/BertoldVdb/ZoneDetect) - C library
- [Timeshape](https://github.com/RomanIakovlev/timeshape) - Java library
- [TimeZoneMap](https://github.com/dustin-johnson/timezonemap) - Java and Android library
- [lutz](https://github.com/ateucher/lutz) - R library
- [go-tz](https://github.com/ugjka/go-tz) - Go library
- [Timezone lookup](https://github.com/evanoberholster/timezoneLookup) - Go library
- [docker-timezone-lookup](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/tobias74/timezone-lookup) -  docker container wrapping node-geo-tz
- [tzf](https://github.com/ringsaturn/tzf) - Go library
- [tzfpy](https://github.com/ringsaturn/tzfpy) - Python port of `tzf` library
- [tzf-rs](https://github.com/ringsaturn/tzf-rs) - Rust port of `tzf` library

Implementations that use the older tz_world data

- [latlong](https://github.com/bradfitz/latlong) - Go library (Read [this post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+BradFitzpatrick/posts/XVyy1bAzkZd) also.)
- [TimeZoneMapper](https://sites.google.com/a/edval.biz/www/mapping-lat-lng-s-to-timezones) - Java library
- [tzwhere](https://github.com/mattbornski/tzwhere) - JavaScript/Node library
- [pytzwhere](https://github.com/pegler/pytzwhere) - Python library
- [timezone_finder](https://github.com/gunyarakun/timezone_finder) - Ruby library
- [LatLongToTimeZone](https://github.com/drtimcooper/LatLongToTimezone) - Java and Swift libraries
- [What Time is it here?](https://derickrethans.nl/what-time-is-it.html) - Blog post describing PHP and MongoDB
- [rundel/timezone](https://github.com/rundel/timezone) - R library

Implementations with its own data

- [Geo::Location::TimeZone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::Location::TimeZone) - Perl library

**Libraries that call one of the web services**

- [timezone](https://rubygems.org/gems/timezone) - Ruby gem that calls GeoNames
- [AskGeo](https://askgeo.com/#libraries) has its own libraries for calling from Java or .Net
- [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html) has client libraries for just about everything

**Self-hosted web services**

- [geo2tz](https://github.com/noandrea/geo2tz) - based on [Timezone lookup](https://github.com/evanoberholster/timezoneLookup), available via Docker image

**Other Ideas**

- Find the nearest city [with an R-Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584826/634824)
- Find the nearest city [with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849653/634824)

*Please update this list if you know of any others*

Also, note that the nearest-city approach may not yield the "correct" result, just an approximation.

**Conversion To Windows Zones**

Most of the methods listed will return an IANA time zone id.  If you need to convert to a Windows time zone for use with the `TimeZoneInfo` class in .NET, use the [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.

**Don't use zone.tab**

The [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) includes a file called [`zone.tab`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone.tab).  This file is primarily used to present a list of time zones for a user to pick from.  It includes the latitude and longitude coordinates for the point of reference for each time zone.  This allows a map to be created highlighting these points.  For example, see the interactive map shown on [the moment-timezone home page](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

While it may be tempting to use this data to resolve the time zone from a latitude and longitude coordinates, consider that these are points - not boundaries.  The best one could do would be to determine the *closest* point, which in many cases will not be the correct point.

Consider the following example:

[image: Time Zone Example Art]

The two squares represent different time zones, where the black dot in each square is the reference location, such as what can be found in zone.tab.  The blue dot represents the location we are attempting to find a time zone for.  Clearly, this location is within the orange zone on the left, but if we just look at closest distance to the reference point, it will resolve to the greenish zone on the right.

Comment: GeoNames is actually perfect for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt However, as I understand, at the moment there is no offline database which would provide timezone info and offset from UTC based on the location coordinates?

Comment: @MattJohnson  how can i use geonames client libraries

Comment: This is a fantastic list, thank you! Google looks like the obvious choice, but I was surprised to find they tell me London is in GMT, when in fact it is in BST at the moment. For New York it had the correct summer adjustment.

Comment: @Lewis42 Check the timestamp you pass in the request, and if still inaccurate, please report to Google's support.  Thanks.

Comment: These new Google API rates are extortionate. 200 request for $1 as of 7/18. That's a 10X increase.

Comment: We currently use Google Api to only fetch time zones and we want to go away because for us doesn't make sense to use the google API and pay for it to "just" retrieve timezones info from lat/lng. I'm wondering also if AWS offer any kind of similar service, maybe cheaper.

Comment: Consider that some of the offered services do not (yet) support https.

Comment: Which are all open source out of the list provided for java?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar - The language of each library is included in the list.  The top current recommendation for Java is [TimeShape](https://github.com/RomanIakovlev/timeshape).

Answer (score 10):

How about this solution for node.js
https://github.com/mattbornski/tzwhere

And its Python counterpart:
https://github.com/pegler/pytzwhere

Comment: I added these to the community wiki answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

We at [Teleport](http://teleport.org) just started [opening up our API's](http://developers.teleport.org/api/getting_started/) and one of the usecases is also exposing TZ information for coordinates.

For example one could request all our available TZ information for coordinates in following manner:

```bash
curl -s https://api.teleport.org/api/locations/59.4372,24.7453/?embed=location:nearest-cities/location:nearest-city/city:timezone/tz:offsets-now | jq '._embedded."location:nearest-cities"[0]._embedded."location:nearest-city"._embedded."city:timezone"'
```

This would return the following

```json
{
  "_embedded": {
    "tz:offsets-now": {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/offsets/?date=2015-09-07T11%3A20%3A09Z"
        }
      },
      "base_offset_min": 120,
      "dst_offset_min": 60,
      "end_time": "2015-10-25T01:00:00Z",
      "short_name": "EEST",
      "total_offset_min": 180,
      "transition_time": "2015-03-29T01:00:00Z"
    }
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/"
    },
    "tz:offsets": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/offsets/{?date}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "tz:offsets-now": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/offsets/?date=2015-09-07T11%3A20%3A09Z"
    }
  },
  "iana_name": "Europe/Tallinn"
}
```

For the example I used [./jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for JSON parsing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Is it doing a nearest-city approach, or are you using a point-in-polygon approach?  (See my diagram with the two squares above.)

Comment: Hi Joonathan, it's the first time I see object or array names like yours in json 

 for example this one:
      "location:nearest-cities":[

How can I reach the result later?
 $city = $data->_embedded->location:nearest->cities[0]->_links->location:nearest->cities->name
this is not allowed

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can use Google's script editor to get the timezoneName and timeZoneId inside a gsheet.

[image]

Step 1. [Get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start) for Google's timezone API

Step 2. Create a new gsheet. Underneath the 'tools' menu click 'script editor'. Add the following code:

```
function getTimezone(lat, long) {  
  var apiKey = 'INSERTAPIKEYHERE'
  var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&timestamp=1331161200&key=' + apiKey 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return data["timeZoneName"];
}
```

Step 3. Save and publish your `getTimezone()` function and use it as shown in the image above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [geolocator.js](https://github.com/onury/geolocator) for easily getting timezone and more...

It uses Google APIs that require a key. So, first you configure geolocator:

```js
geolocator.config({
    language: "en",
    google: {
        version: "3",
        key: "YOUR-GOOGLE-API-KEY"
    }
});
```

**Get TimeZone if you have the coordinates:**

```js
geolocator.getTimeZone(options, function (err, timezone) {
    console.log(err || timezone);
});
```

**Example output:**

```js
{
    id: "Europe/Paris",
    name: "Central European Standard Time",
    abbr: "CEST",
    dstOffset: 0,
    rawOffset: 3600,
    timestamp: 1455733120
}
```

**Locate then get TimeZone and more**

If you don't have the coordinates, you can locate the user position first.

Example below will first try HTML5 Geolocation API to get the coordinates. If it fails or rejected, it will get the coordinates via Geo-IP look-up. Finally, it will get the timezone and more...

```js
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 6000,
    maximumAge: 0,
    desiredAccuracy: 30,
    fallbackToIP: true, // if HTML5 fails or rejected
    addressLookup: true, // this will get full address information
    timezone: true,
    map: "my-map" // this will even create a map for you
};
geolocator.locate(options, function (err, location) {
    console.log(err || location);
});
```

**Example output:**

```js
{
    coords: {
        latitude: 37.4224764,
        longitude: -122.0842499,
        accuracy: 30,
        altitude: null,
        altitudeAccuracy: null,
        heading: null,
        speed: null
    },
    address: {
        commonName: "",
        street: "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
        route: "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
        streetNumber: "1600",
        neighborhood: "",
        town: "",
        city: "Mountain View",
        region: "Santa Clara County",
        state: "California",
        stateCode: "CA",
        postalCode: "94043",
        country: "United States",
        countryCode: "US"
    },
    formattedAddress: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    type: "ROOFTOP",
    placeId: "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
    timezone: {
        id: "America/Los_Angeles",
        name: "Pacific Standard Time",
        abbr: "PST",
        dstOffset: 0,
        rawOffset: -28800
    },
    flag: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.3.1/flags/4x3/us.svg",
    map: {
        element: HTMLElement,
        instance: Object, // google.maps.Map
        marker: Object, // google.maps.Marker
        infoWindow: Object, // google.maps.InfoWindow
        options: Object // map options
    },
    timestamp: 1456795956380
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a package https://github.com/ringsaturn/tzf support get timezone in Go&Python and very fast:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ringsaturn/tzf"
)

func main() {
    finder, err := tzf.NewDefaultFinder()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(finder.GetTimezoneName(116.6386, 40.0786))
}
```

Python https://github.com/ringsaturn/tzfpy sample:

```py
from tzfpy import get_tz

print(get_tz(121.4737, 31.2305))
```

Rust https://github.com/ringsaturn/tzf-rs sample:

```rust
use tzf_rs::DefaultFinder;

fn main() {
    let finder = DefaultFinder::new();

    print!("{:?}\n", DefaultFinder.get_tz_name(116.3883, 39.9289));
}
```

Comment: I added this to the list in the main answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Hi I have updated and add Python&Rust port’s link, can you add them to the main answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed important to recognize that this a more complicated problem than most would suspect. In practice many of us are also willing to accept a working set of code that works for "as many cases as possible", where at least its fatal issues can be identified and minimized collectively. So I post this with all of that and the spirit of the OP in mind. Finally, for practical value to others who are trying to convert GPS to timezone with the end goal of having a location-sensitive time object (and more importantly to help advance the quality of average implementations with time objects that follow from this wiki) here is what I generated in Python (please feel free to edit):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from tzwhere import tzwhere

def timezoned_unixtime(latitude, longitude, dt):
    tzw = tzwhere.tzwhere()
    timezone_str = tzw.tzNameAt(latitude, longitude)
    timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone_str)
    timezone_aware_datetime = timezone.localize(dt, is_dst=None)
    unix_time = (timezone_aware_datetime - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
    return unix_time

dt = datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=17, hour=12, minute=0, second=0)
print timezoned_unixtime(latitude=40.747854, longitude=-74.004733, dt=dt)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like some code that uses [pytzwhere](https://github.com/pegler/pytzwhere) which is already listed in the main community wiki answer.  If you meant to provide a sample of how to combine pytzwhere with pytz, you might want to submit that as a PR to the pytzwhere project itself.  Here we are just looking for lat/lon to tz solutions - of which pytzwhere is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**disclosure: I am the author of the docker-image described below**

I have wrapped https://github.com/evansiroky/node-geo-tz in a very simple docker-container

> https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/tobias74/timezone-lookup

You can start the docker-container with

```
docker run -p 80:3000 tobias74/timezone-lookup:latest
```

This exposes the lookup-service on your localhost on port 3000. You can then do a timezone-lookup by

```
curl "localhost:3000/timezone?latitude=12&longitude=34"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get time zone you can use the Web-service [GeoTimeZone.com](https://www.geotimezone.com).

The web-service is quite simple, but it returns full time zone information, including the IANA identifier, abbreviation and offset.

Sample curl command to use this service: `curl -v "https://api.geotimezone.com/public/timezone?longitude=12.45726&latitude=41.90224"`

Typical output of the web service:

```
{
   "longitude": 12.45726,
   "latitude": 41.90224,
   "location": "Vatican City",
   "country_iso": "VA",
   "iana_timezone": "Europe/Vatican",
   "timezone_abbreviation": "CET",
   "dst_abbreviation": "CEST",
   "offset": "UTC+1",
   "dst_offset": "UTC+2",
   "current_local_datetime": "2023-11-17T15:44:39.897",
   "current_utc_datetime": "2023-11-17T14:44:39.897Z"
}
```

Comment: IMHO, It would be helpful if the author of that service were to give a more detailed explanation of its source data.  It says it comes from OSM, but it doesn't clarify if the boundaries are from TZBB (which is based on OSM), or if it has its own data set.  Also a statement of production readiness and terms of service would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for use Google Time Zone API from Java with current NTP Time Client and correct UTC_Datetime_from_timestamp convert:

```java
String get_xml_server_reponse(String server_url){

    URL xml_server = null;

    String xmltext = "";

    InputStream input;


    try {
        xml_server = new URL(server_url);


        try {
            input = xml_server.openConnection().getInputStream();


            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            final StringBuilder sBuf = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    sBuf.append(line);
                }
               } 
            catch (IOException e) 
              {
                    Log.e(e.getMessage(), "XML parser, stream2string 1");
              } 
            finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.e(e.getMessage(), "XML parser, stream2string 2");
                }
            }

            xmltext =  sBuf.toString();

        } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

          e1.printStackTrace();
        }

     return  xmltext;

  }     


 private String get_UTC_Datetime_from_timestamp(long timeStamp){

    try{

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

        int tzt = tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());

        timeStamp -= tzt;

        // DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault());
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return sdf.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return "";
     }
    } 

 class NTP_UTC_Time
 {
     private static final String TAG = "SntpClient";

     private static final int RECEIVE_TIME_OFFSET = 32;
     private static final int TRANSMIT_TIME_OFFSET = 40;
     private static final int NTP_PACKET_SIZE = 48;

     private static final int NTP_PORT = 123;
     private static final int NTP_MODE_CLIENT = 3;
     private static final int NTP_VERSION = 3;

     // Number of seconds between Jan 1, 1900 and Jan 1, 1970
     // 70 years plus 17 leap days
     private static final long OFFSET_1900_TO_1970 = ((365L * 70L) + 17L) * 24L * 60L * 60L;

     private long mNtpTime;

     public boolean requestTime(String host, int timeout) {
         try {
             DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
             socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
             InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
             byte[] buffer = new byte[NTP_PACKET_SIZE];
             DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, NTP_PORT);

             buffer[0] = NTP_MODE_CLIENT | (NTP_VERSION << 3);

             writeTimeStamp(buffer, TRANSMIT_TIME_OFFSET);

             socket.send(request);

             // read the response
             DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
             socket.receive(response);          
             socket.close();

             mNtpTime = readTimeStamp(buffer, RECEIVE_TIME_OFFSET);            
         } catch (Exception e) {
           //  if (Config.LOGD) Log.d(TAG, "request time failed: " + e);
             return false;
         }

         return true;
     }


     public long getNtpTime() {
         return mNtpTime;
     }


     /**
      * Reads an unsigned 32 bit big endian number from the given offset in the buffer.
      */
     private long read32(byte[] buffer, int offset) {
         byte b0 = buffer[offset];
         byte b1 = buffer[offset+1];
         byte b2 = buffer[offset+2];
         byte b3 = buffer[offset+3];

         // convert signed bytes to unsigned values
         int i0 = ((b0 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b0 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b0);
         int i1 = ((b1 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b1 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b1);
         int i2 = ((b2 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b2 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b2);
         int i3 = ((b3 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b3 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b3);

         return ((long)i0 << 24) + ((long)i1 << 16) + ((long)i2 << 8) + (long)i3;
     }

     /**
      * Reads the NTP time stamp at the given offset in the buffer and returns 
      * it as a system time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970).
      */    
     private long readTimeStamp(byte[] buffer, int offset) {
         long seconds = read32(buffer, offset);
         long fraction = read32(buffer, offset + 4);
         return ((seconds - OFFSET_1900_TO_1970) * 1000) + ((fraction * 1000L) / 0x100000000L);        
     }

     /**
      * Writes 0 as NTP starttime stamp in the buffer. --> Then NTP returns Time OFFSET since 1900
      */    
     private void writeTimeStamp(byte[] buffer, int offset) {        
         int ofs =  offset++;

         for (int i=ofs;i<(ofs+8);i++)
           buffer[i] = (byte)(0);             
     }

 }

 String get_time_zone_time(GeoPoint gp){

        String erg = "";
        String raw_offset = "";
        String dst_offset = "";

        double Longitude = gp.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
        double Latitude = gp.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;



        long tsLong = 0; // System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

        NTP_UTC_Time client = new NTP_UTC_Time();

        if (client.requestTime("pool.ntp.org", 2000)) {              
          tsLong = client.getNtpTime();
        }

        if (tsLong != 0)
        {

        tsLong = tsLong  / 1000;

        // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false

        String request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml?location="+Latitude+","+ Longitude+ "&timestamp="+tsLong +"&sensor=false";

        String xmltext = get_xml_server_reponse(request);

        if(xmltext.compareTo("")!= 0)
        {

         int startpos = xmltext.indexOf("<TimeZoneResponse");
         xmltext = xmltext.substring(startpos);



        XmlPullParser parser;
        try {
            parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();


             parser.setInput(new StringReader (xmltext));

             int eventType = parser.getEventType();  

             String tagName = "";


             while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                 switch(eventType) {

                     case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                           tagName = parser.getName();

                         break;


                     case XmlPullParser.TEXT :


                        if  (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("raw_offset"))
                          if(raw_offset.compareTo("")== 0)                               
                            raw_offset = parser.getText();  

                        if  (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("dst_offset"))
                          if(dst_offset.compareTo("")== 0)
                            dst_offset = parser.getText();  


                        break;   

                 }

                 try {
                        eventType = parser.next();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    erg += e.toString();
                }

        }      

        int ro = 0;
        if(raw_offset.compareTo("")!= 0)
        { 
            float rof = str_to_float(raw_offset);
            ro = (int)rof;
        }

        int dof = 0;
        if(dst_offset.compareTo("")!= 0)
        { 
            float doff = str_to_float(dst_offset);
            dof = (int)doff;
        }

        tsLong = (tsLong + ro + dof) * 1000;



        erg = get_UTC_Datetime_from_timestamp(tsLong);
        }


  return erg;

}
```

And use it with:

```java
GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(39.6034810,-119.6822510);
String Current_TimeZone_Time = get_time_zone_time(gp);
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of code for a simple task.  You've got a full NTP client in there, which might be a good idea - but is not necessarily required.  Can you slim it down a bit please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the short Version without correct NTP Time:

```
String get_xml_server_reponse(String server_url){

URL xml_server = null;

String xmltext = "";

InputStream input;


try {
    xml_server = new URL(server_url);


    try {
        input = xml_server.openConnection().getInputStream();


        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        final StringBuilder sBuf = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sBuf.append(line);
            }
           } 
        catch (IOException e) 
          {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), "XML parser, stream2string 1");
          } 
        finally {
            try {
                input.close();
                }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), "XML parser, stream2string 2");
            }
        }

        xmltext =  sBuf.toString();

    } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

      e1.printStackTrace();
    }

 return  xmltext;

} 


long get_time_zone_time_l(GeoPoint gp){


        String raw_offset = "";
        String dst_offset = "";

        double Longitude = gp.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
        double Latitude = gp.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;

        long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;


        if (tsLong != 0)
        {

        // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false

        String request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml?location="+Latitude+","+ Longitude+ "&timestamp="+tsLong +"&sensor=false";

        String xmltext = get_xml_server_reponse(request);

        if(xmltext.compareTo("")!= 0)
        {

         int startpos = xmltext.indexOf("<TimeZoneResponse");
         xmltext = xmltext.substring(startpos);



        XmlPullParser parser;
        try {
            parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();


             parser.setInput(new StringReader (xmltext));

             int eventType = parser.getEventType();  

             String tagName = "";


             while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                 switch(eventType) {

                     case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                           tagName = parser.getName();

                         break;


                     case XmlPullParser.TEXT :


                        if  (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("raw_offset"))
                          if(raw_offset.compareTo("")== 0)                               
                            raw_offset = parser.getText();  

                        if  (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("dst_offset"))
                          if(dst_offset.compareTo("")== 0)
                            dst_offset = parser.getText();  


                        break;   

                 }

                 try {
                        eventType = parser.next();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    erg += e.toString();
                }

        }      

        int ro = 0;
        if(raw_offset.compareTo("")!= 0)
        { 
            float rof = str_to_float(raw_offset);
            ro = (int)rof;
        }

        int dof = 0;
        if(dst_offset.compareTo("")!= 0)
        { 
            float doff = str_to_float(dst_offset);
            dof = (int)doff;
        }

        tsLong = (tsLong + ro + dof) * 1000;


        }


  return tsLong;

}
```

And use it with:

```
GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(39.6034810,-119.6822510);
long Current_TimeZone_Time_l = get_time_zone_time_l(gp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use geonames.org then use this code. (But geonames.org is very slow sometimes)

```
String get_time_zone_time_geonames(GeoPoint gp){


        String erg = "";

        double Longitude = gp.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
        double Latitude = gp.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;



        String request = "http://ws.geonames.org/timezone?lat="+Latitude+"&lng="+ Longitude+ "&style=full";

        URL time_zone_time = null;

        InputStream input;
       // final StringBuilder sBuf = new StringBuilder();


        try {
            time_zone_time = new URL(request);


        try {
            input = time_zone_time.openConnection().getInputStream();


        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            final StringBuilder sBuf = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuf.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(e.getMessage(), "XML parser, stream2string 1");
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(e.getMessage(), "XML parser, stream2string 2");
                }
            }




             String xmltext = sBuf.toString();


             int startpos = xmltext.indexOf("<geonames");
             xmltext = xmltext.substring(startpos);



            XmlPullParser parser;
            try {
                parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();


            parser.setInput(new StringReader (xmltext));

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();  

            String tagName = "";

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch(eventType) {

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                          tagName = parser.getName();

                        break;


                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT :


                        if  (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("time"))
                          erg = parser.getText();  


                    break;   

                }

                try {
                    eventType = parser.next();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                erg += e.toString();
            }



            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }





        return erg;

 }
```

And use it with:

```
GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(39.6034810,-119.6822510);
String Current_TimeZone_Time = get_time_zone_time_geonames(gp);
```

Answer (score 0):

by using latitude and longitude get time zone of current location below code worked for me

```
String data = null;         
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location ll = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
double lat = 0,lng = 0;
if(ll!=null){
    lat=ll.getLatitude();
    lng=ll.getLongitude();
}
System.out.println(" Last known location of device  == "+lat+"    "+lng);

InputStream iStream = null; 
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try{
    timezoneurl = timezoneurl+"location=22.7260783,75.8781553&timestamp=1331161200";                    
    // timezoneurl = timezoneurl+"location="+lat+","+lng+"&timestamp=1331161200";

    URL url = new URL(timezoneurl);                
    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

    // Connecting to url 
    urlConnection.connect();                

    // Reading data from url 
    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

    StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
        sb.append(line);
    }
    data = sb.toString();
    br.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
}finally{
    try {
        iStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}

try {
    if(data!=null){
        JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(data);
        timezoneId = jobj.getString("timeZoneId");

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId));

        Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId));
        System.out.println("time zone id in android ==  "+timezoneId);

        System.out.println("time zone of  device in android == "+TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId));
        System.out.println("time fo device in android "+cl.getTime());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Which service are you calling?  And did you *really* want to share your keys with us??

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

And here is a good implementation using JSON data:
https://github.com/agap/llttz

```
public TimeZone nearestTimeZone(Location node) {
    double bestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    Location bestGuess = timeZones.get(0);

    for (Location current : timeZones.subList(1, timeZones.size())) {
        double newDistance = distanceInKilometers(node, current);

        if (newDistance < bestDistance) {
            bestDistance = newDistance;
            bestGuess = current;
        }
    }

    return java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(bestGuess.getZone());
}

  protected double distanceInKilometers(final double latFrom, final double lonFrom, final double latTo, final double lonTo) {
        final double meridianLength = 111.1;
        return meridianLength * centralAngle(latFrom, lonFrom, latTo, lonTo);
    }

    protected double centralAngle(final Location from, final Location to) {
        return centralAngle(from.getLatitude(), from.getLongitude(), to.getLatitude(), to.getLongitude());
    }

    protected double centralAngle(final double latFrom, final double lonFrom, final double latTo, final double lonTo) {
        final double latFromRad = toRadians(latFrom),
                lonFromRad = toRadians(lonFrom),
                latToRad   = toRadians(latTo),
                lonToRad   = toRadians(lonTo);

        final double centralAngle = toDegrees(acos(sin(latFromRad) * sin(latToRad) + cos(latFromRad) * cos(latToRad) * cos(lonToRad - lonFromRad)));

        return centralAngle <= 180.0 ? centralAngle : (360.0 - centralAngle);
    }

    protected double distanceInKilometers(final Location from, final Location to) {
        return distanceInKilometers(from.getLatitude(), from.getLongitude(), to.getLatitude(), to.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add some content from the links?

Answer (score 0):

From Guppy:

```
import geocoders
g = geocoders.GoogleV3()
place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode('Fairbanks')
print place, (lat, lng)
Fairbanks, AK, USA (64.8377778, -147.7163889)
timezone = g.timezone((lat, lng))
print timezone.dst
```

Bound method `America/Anchorage.dst` of `DstTzInfo`

**America/Anchorage' LMT-1 day, 14:00:00 STD**

Comment: I think Guppy is a typo.  Do you mean [Geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are several sources online that have geojson data for timezones ([here's one](https://github.com/straup/whereonearth-timezone), [here's](https://github.com/candu/efele-tz-world-geojson/blob/master/tz_world.geojson) another)
2. Use a geometry library to create polygon objects from the geojson coordinates ([shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) [python], [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) [c++], [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/?f) [java], [NTS](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) [.net]).
3. Convert your lat/lng to a point object (however your library represents that) and check if it intersects the timezone polygon.

   ```
   from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

   def get_tz_from_lat_lng(lat, lng):
       for tz, geojson in timezones.iteritems():
           coordinates = geojson['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
           polygon = Polygon(coordinates)
           point = Point(lng, lat)
           if polygon.contains(point):
               return tz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**For those of us using Javascript and looking to get a timezone from a zip code via Google APIs**, here is one method.

1. Fetch the lat/lng via geolocation
2. fetch the timezone by pass that
   into the [timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_433476780412-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20~%20Time%20Zone%20API-KWID_43700039136946363-kwd-538188851010-userloc_9001865&utm_term=KW_%2Btime%20%2Bzone%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Btime%20%2Bzone%20%2Bapi&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI66HVxtaz6QIVB2yGCh2QnwFuEAAYASAAEgKOXPD_BwE).

   - Using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) here for timezone conversion.

Note: my understanding is that zipcodes are not unique across countries, so this is likely best suited for use in the USA.

```
const googleMapsClient; // instantiate your client here
const zipcode = '90210'
const myDateThatNeedsTZAdjustment; // define your date that needs adjusting
// fetch lat/lng from google api by zipcode
const geocodeResponse = await googleMapsClient.geocode({ address: zipcode }).asPromise();
if (geocodeResponse.json.status === 'OK') {
  lat = geocodeResponse.json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
  lng = geocodeResponse.json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
} else {
  console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}

// prepare lat/lng and timestamp of profile created_at to fetch time zone
const location = `${lat},${lng}`;
const timestamp = new Date().valueOf() / 1000;
const timezoneResponse = await googleMapsClient
  .timezone({ location: location, timestamp: timestamp })
  .asPromise();

const timeZoneId = timezoneResponse.json.timeZoneId;
// adjust by setting timezone
const timezoneAdjustedDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(
  myDateThatNeedsTZAdjustment
).setZone(timeZoneId);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you prefer to avoid a web service, you can retrieve that information from the browser like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var usertime = d.toLocaleString();

//some browsers / OSs provide the timezone name in their local string
var tzsregex = /\b(ACDT|ACST|ACT|ADT|AEDT|AEST|AFT|AKDT|AKST|AMST|AMT|ART|AST|AWDT|AWST|AZOST|AZT|BDT|BIOT|BIT|BOT|BRT|BST|BTT|CAT|CCT|CDT|CEDT|CEST|CET|CHADT|CHAST|CIST|CKT|CLST|CLT|COST|COT|CST|CT|CVT|CXT|CHST|DFT|EAST|EAT|ECT|EDT|EEDT|EEST|EET|EST|FJT|FKST|FKT|GALT|GET|GFT|GILT|GIT|GMT|GST|GYT|HADT|HAEC|HAST|HKT|HMT|HST|ICT|IDT|IRKT|IRST|IST|JST|KRAT|KST|LHST|LINT|MART|MAGT|MDT|MET|MEST|MIT|MSD|MSK|MST|MUT|MYT|NDT|NFT|NPT|NST|NT|NZDT|NZST|OMST|PDT|PETT|PHOT|PKT|PST|RET|SAMT|SAST|SBT|SCT|SGT|SLT|SST|TAHT|THA|UYST|UYT|VET|VLAT|WAT|WEDT|WEST|WET|WST|YAKT|YEKT)\b/gi;

//in other browsers the timezone needs to be estimated based on the offset
var timezonenames = {"UTC+0":"GMT","UTC+1":"CET","UTC+2":"EET","UTC+3":"EEDT","UTC+3.5":"IRST","UTC+4":"MSD","UTC+4.5":"AFT","UTC+5":"PKT","UTC+5.5":"IST","UTC+6":"BST","UTC+6.5":"MST","UTC+7":"THA","UTC+8":"AWST","UTC+9":"AWDT","UTC+9.5":"ACST","UTC+10":"AEST","UTC+10.5":"ACDT","UTC+11":"AEDT","UTC+11.5":"NFT","UTC+12":"NZST","UTC-1":"AZOST","UTC-2":"GST","UTC-3":"BRT","UTC-3.5":"NST","UTC-4":"CLT","UTC-4.5":"VET","UTC-5":"EST","UTC-6":"CST","UTC-7":"MST","UTC-8":"PST","UTC-9":"AKST","UTC-9.5":"MIT","UTC-10":"HST","UTC-11":"SST","UTC-12":"BIT"};

var timezone = usertime.match(tzsregex);
if (timezone) {
    timezone = timezone[timezone.length-1];
} else {
    var offset = -1*d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
    offset = "UTC" + (offset >= 0 ? "+" + offset : offset);
    timezone = timezonenames[offset];
}

//there are 3 variables can use to see the timezone
// usertime - full date
// offset - UTC offset time
// timezone - country

console.log('Full Date: ' + usertime);
console.log('UTC Offset: ' + offset);
console.log('Country Code Timezone: ' + timezone);
```

In my current case it is printing:

**Full Date:** ‎27‎/‎01‎/‎2014‎ ‎16‎:‎53‎:‎37
**UTC Offset:** UTC-3
**Country Code Timezone:** BRT

Hope it can be helpful.

Comment: While I appreciate you put some effort into this, please realize:  1) Time zones are not fixed offsets 2) Time zone abbreviations are not standardized or unique identifiers 3) This has already been done, much more accurately, with [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/).  4) Your answer doesn't match the question.  The question was how to determine a time zone **from latitude and longitude coordinates**.

Answer (score -4):

```js
  function jsonpRequest(url, data)
{
    let params = "";
    for (let key in data)
    {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            if (params.length == 0)
            {
                params += "?";
            }
            else
            {
                params += "&";
            }
            let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
            let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
            params += encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue;
         }
    }
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url + params;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
let lat_ini=[]; let lon_ini=[];
function showPosition(position) {
  lat_ini= position.coords.latitude;
  lon_ini= position.coords.longitude;
}
////delay time between lines
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
///////
function getGMT()
{
  getfinalGMT()
  getLocation()
  async function sample() {
    await sleep(2000);
let lat_str=lat_ini.toString();
let lng_str=" "+lon_ini.toString();

  let url = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json";
  let data = {
    callback: "displayGMT",
    q: lat_str + lng_str,
    key: "fac4471073a347019196c1291e6a97d7"
  }
  jsonpRequest(url, data)
}
 sample();
 }
let your_GMT=[];
function displayGMT(data)
{
your_GMT=(Number(data.results[0].annotations.timezone.offset_string))
console.log(your_GMT)
}
/////
function getfinalGMT()
{
let lat=document.getElementById("lat_id").value; let lng=document.getElementById("lng_id").value;
let lat_str=lat.toString();
let lng_str=" "+lng.toString();

  let url = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json";
  let data = {
    callback: "displayfinalGMT",
    q: lat + lng_str,
    key: "fac4471073a347019196c1291e6a97d7"
  }
  jsonpRequest(url, data)
 }
let final_GMT=[];
function displayfinalGMT(data)
{
final_GMT=(Number(data.results[0].annotations.timezone.offset_string))
console.log(final_GMT)
}
/////clock


const hourHand = document.querySelector('[data-hour-hand]')
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('[data-minute-hand]')
const secondHand = document.querySelector('[data-second-hand]')
  let dif_overall=[];
function setClock() {
   let gmt_diff=Number(your_GMT-final_GMT)/100
   if (gmt_diff>12){
      dif_overall=gmt_diff-12
   }
   else{
     dif_overall=gmt_diff
   }
    console.log(dif_overall)
  const currentDate = new Date()
  const secondsRatio = currentDate.getSeconds() / 60
  const minutesRatio = (secondsRatio + currentDate.getMinutes()) / 60
  const hoursRatio = (minutesRatio + currentDate.getHours() - dif_overall ) / 12
  setRotation(secondHand, secondsRatio)
  setRotation(minuteHand, minutesRatio)
  setRotation(hourHand, hoursRatio)
}

function setRotation(element, rotationRatio) {
  element.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotationRatio * 360)
}
function activate_clock(){
setClock()
setInterval(setClock, 1000)
}
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(200, 100%, 50%), hsl(175, 100%, 50%));
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 { --rotation: 30deg; }
.clock .number2 { --rotation: 60deg; }
.clock .number3 { --rotation: 90deg; }
.clock .number4 { --rotation: 120deg; }
.clock .number5 { --rotation: 150deg; }
.clock .number6 { --rotation: 180deg; }
.clock .number7 { --rotation: 210deg; }
.clock .number8 { --rotation: 240deg; }
.clock .number9 { --rotation: 270deg; }
.clock .number10 { --rotation: 300deg; }
.clock .number11 { --rotation: 330deg; }

.clock .hand {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second {
  width: 3px;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute {
  width: 7px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: black;
}

.clock .hand.hour {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: black;
}














/* Background Styles Only */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

* {
    font-family: Raleway;
}

.side-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.side-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.side-link-youtube {
  background-color: red;
}

.side-link-twitter {
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}

.side-link-github {
  background-color: #6e5494;
}

.side-link-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.side-link-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
   <input type="text" id="lat_id" placeholder="lat"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="lng_id" placeholder="lng"><br><br>
<button class="text" onClick="getLocation()">Location</button>
<button class="text" onClick="getGMT()"> GMT</button>
<button class="text" onClick="activate_clock()"> Activate</button>
<div class="clock">
  <div class="hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
  <div class="hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
  <div class="hand second" data-second-hand></div>
  <div class="number number1">1</div>
  <div class="number number2">2</div>
  <div class="number number3">3</div>
  <div class="number number4">4</div>
  <div class="number number5">5</div>
  <div class="number number6">6</div>
  <div class="number number7">7</div>
  <div class="number number8">8</div>
  <div class="number number9">9</div>
  <div class="number number10">10</div>
  <div class="number number11">11</div>
  <div class="number number12">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guys you will have to copy and paste the code into a new browser as code snippet will not allow us to prompt for the user's location

Comment: Hope you guys appreciate it

Comment: Once enter lat and lng, press on location,GMT then activate the clock

Comment: I really don't think you meant to share your API key to opencagedata with us, did you?  Instead of dumping code, you could simply describe this API.

Comment: Well, some people just need to see a sample of callback function to api to better understand

Comment: Your code answers a different question than the one that was asked.  It doesn't demonstrate how to retrieve the IANA time zone name from the API call.  Since opencagedata API does return that, you should modify your answer to simply present it instead of drawing an animation of a clock with hands.  Also, you should remove your API key, and change it with opencagedata so others can't access your account.

Comment: Additionally, parsing the GMT offset assumes that the offset won't ever change.  One would have to make a new call to get the new offset after a DST transition.